# Python - Date Diff by Multiple Anchor Points

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to find the date diff by certain anchor points between IDs. To elaborate more about the anchor points, they are simply dates of interest that I have in my data set. An ID may have one, two three, or more anchor points.

The dates prior to the first anchor point should be associated to the first anchor. If there is only one anchor, then all dates should be associated to the first anchor. If there is a second anchor for the same ID, then all dates after the first anchor should be associated to the second anchor date. If there is a third anchor point, then all dates after the second anchor should be associated to the third, etc.

Input

```
ID  Date        Anchor
123 1/5/2018    N
123 4/10/2018   N
123 5/8/2018    Y
123 5/10/2018   N
123 6/14/2018   N
123 7/8/2018    Y
123 8/2/2018    N
123 10/3/2018   N
234 1/4/2018    N
234 2/5/2018    Y 
234 4/10/2018   N
234 5/6/2018    Y
```

Expected Output:

```
ID  Date        Anchor   Date Diff (Days)
123 1/5/2018    N       -123
123 4/10/2018   N       -28
123 5/8/2018    Y        0
123 5/10/2018   N       -59
123 6/14/2018   N       -24
123 7/8/2018    Y        0
123 8/2/2018    N        25
123 10/3/2018   N        87
234 1/4/2018    N       -32
234 2/5/2018    Y        0
234 4/10/2018   N       -26
234 5/6/2018    Y        0
```

Code Attempt

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.groupby('ID')

anchors = dict()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Anchor Date'] == 'Y':
        if row['ID'] in anchors:
            anchors[row['ID']].append(row['Date'])
        else:
            anchors[row['ID']] = [row['Date']]

daysDifference = list()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Anchor Date'] == 'N':
        delta = 9999 #Arbitrary value
        for anchorDate in anchors[row['ID']]:
            if abs((row['Date'] - anchorDate).days) < delta:
                delta = (row['Date'] - anchorDate).days
        daysDifference.append(delta)
    else:
        daysDifference.append(0)

df['Diff'] = daysDifference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` and `groupby.bfill` to to the job, use `ffill` to complete the filling.

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['diff_'] = (s - s.where(df['Anchor'].eq('Y'))
                    .groupby(df['ID'])
                    .apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill())
              ).dt.days
print (df)
     ID       Date Anchor  diff_
0   123   1/5/2018      N   -123
1   123  4/10/2018      N    -28
2   123   5/8/2018      Y      0
3   123  5/10/2018      N    -59
4   123  6/14/2018      N    -24
5   123   7/8/2018      Y      0
6   123   8/2/2018      N     25
7   123  10/3/2018      N     87
8   234   1/4/2018      N    -32
9   234   2/5/2018      Y      0
10  234  4/10/2018      N    -26
11  234   5/6/2018      Y      0
```